# xcode replace in a line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, replace, nsstring

I want to replace all spaces in a line before a text comes, for example I have the following text:

```
@"  Hello\n   world"
```

and i want it to look like this:

```
@"Hello\nworld"
```

How can you do this for every line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trim white spaces from string. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756256/objective-c-trim-spaces-from-end-of-a-string). There is a solution.