# regex for adding a space between two words if not already there

Tags: objective-c, regex

I would like to add a spacing between two words if its already not there:

```
//Sample 1
NSString *word1 = @"First";
NSString *word2 = @"Word";

NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", word1, word2];
//output = FirstWord --> I want "First Word"
```

If there is already a space "First " then it should not add another one.

Comment: Why do you think you need a regex for this? Why not check if `word1` ends in whitespace or `word2` begins with whitespace and if not, put a space in between them?

Comment: Just [trim the first string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5756256/3141234), and then always put a space.

Answer (score 0):

Just trim the first string, and then always put a space.

```
NSString *word1 = @"First";
NSString *word2 = @"Word";

NSString *word1Trimmed = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", word1Trimmed, word2];
```

Comment: What if `word2` begins with a space? What if `word1` ends in 1,000,000 spaces? Why do the extra work?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm answering the direct question `If there is already a space "First " then it should not add another one.`