# Remove white space from the left of NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsstring

I need to remove the white space only from the left of NSString I mean

if I have `"   This is a good day"` I will have `"This is a good day"`

only the left spaces only

any suggestion please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689288/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-right-end-of-nsstring

Comment: @Jhaliya, See what @AMH needs below :-)

Comment: @Jhaliya, *stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:* this is the method he actually looks for. In his question he asked *"Remove white space from the left of NSString"* because the string in his example has white space at the left end only.

Comment: @Simon : you are right , Got you Simon, I thought, he has some specific requirement to remove from left. you could add your answer.

Comment: @Jhaliya, Answers for his question are already here :-)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just use

```
NSString* result = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

it will remove all extra space from left as well as right but not from middle

and to remove both white space and `\n` use

```
NSString* result = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: how to remove \n using the same method

Comment: for removing new line character what i do, whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet not working that only remove white space

Answer (score 4):

Use below to remove white and new line chatacter from your `NSString`.

```
NSString* result = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: @ Simon :Read my comment on question ?

Comment: +1, For forcing me to delete my answer. Just kidding. +1 for the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Nsstring *str="   This is a good day";

  while ([str rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
}

nslog(@"string after removing space %@",)
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution that does not work correctly for many other possible cases, such as @" This is  a good day", and it leaves a leading space in the string. How did this get upvoted??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with when facing the same issue:

```
- (NSString*)trimBlankCharactersFromBeginningOfString:(NSString*)originalString
{
    //we are only trimming the characters on the left side of the string
    NSInteger count = [originalString length];
    NSString *trimmedNewText = originalString;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if([[originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            trimmedNewText = [originalString substringFromIndex:i];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i+1 < count)
            {
                trimmedNewText = [originalString substringFromIndex:i+1];
            }
            //since we are exiting the loop as soon as a non blank space character is found
            //then this is just really checking to see if we are on the last character of an
            //all whitespace string. can't say i+1 here because that would give an index out
            //of bound exception
            else
            {
                trimmedNewText = @"";
            }
        }
    }
    return trimmedNewText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For trimming only to the left a solution is to add a dummy character to the right of your string, trim the string, and then remove it.

```
NSString* tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@T", yourString];
NSString* result = [yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
return [result substringToIndex:[result length]-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

ONLY the left whitespaces

```
while ([[yourString substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@" "])
    yourString = [yourString substringFromIndex:1];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *str = @" This is a good day";    
NSArray *arrString = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
NSString *strSpace = [arrString objectAtIndex:0];   // White space
NSString *strString = [arrString objectAtIndex:1];   //This is a good day
```

You can then append **T** in the string as

```
NSString *strT = @"T";
strString = [strT stringByAppendingString:strString];
```