# Comparing String ignoring spaces at the beginning or ending

Tags: ios, string, nsstring, swift, spaces

I'm new with iOS developing and i'm looking for a solution to compare two String ignoring the spaces at the beginning or at the ending. For example, "Hello" == "Hello    " should return true.

I've serached for a solution but i didn't find nothing in Swift. Thanks

Comment: Consider trimming the string. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756256/objective-c-trim-spaces-from-end-of-a-string

Comment: Here's a link to a string reference in Swift: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/reference-guides/string-reference-guide-for-swift/. Search that page for "trim".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSString *string1 = @" Hello";
 //remove(trim) whitespaces
 string1 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

 NSString *string2 = @"Hello ";
 //remove(trim) whitespaces
 string2 = [string1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]

 // compare strings without whitespaces
 if ([string1 isEuqalToString:string2]) {
 }
```

So if you want to use it directly -

```
if ([[yourString1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] isEuqalToString:[yourString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]]) {
// Strings are compared without whitespaces.
}
```

Above will remove all whitespaces of your string, if you want to remove only leading and trailing whitespaces then there are a couple of post already available, you can create a category of string as mentioned in following stack overflow post - [How to remove whitespace from right end of NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689288/how-to-remove-whitespace-from-right-end-of-nsstring)

```
@implementation NSString (TrimmingAdditions)

- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingLeadingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterSet {
    NSUInteger location = 0;
    NSUInteger length = [self length];
    unichar charBuffer[length];    
    [self getCharacters:charBuffer];

    for (location; location < length; location++) {
        if (![characterSet characterIsMember:charBuffer[location]]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, length - location)];
}

- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingTrailingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterSet {
    NSUInteger location = 0;
    NSUInteger length = [self length];
    unichar charBuffer[length];    
    [self getCharacters:charBuffer];

    for (length; length > 0; length--) {
        if (![characterSet characterIsMember:charBuffer[length - 1]]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, length - location)];
}

@end
```

Now once you have the methods available, you can call these on your strings to trim leading and trailing spaces like -

```
 // trim leading chars
 yourString1 = [yourString1 stringByTrimmingLeadingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
// trim trainling chars
yourString1 = [yourString1 stringByTrimmingTrailingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

// trim leading chars
 yourString2 = [yourString2 stringByTrimmingLeadingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
// trim trainling chars
yourString2 = [yourString2 stringByTrimmingTrailingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

// compare strings
if([yourString1 isEqualToString: yourString2]) {

}
```

Comment: This removes spaces in the middle of the string, you should use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` to remove only leading and trailing spaces. Also...this isn't even in Swift...

Comment: Though this is the accepted answer, it's not Swift. If you're here... and are looking for Swift... keep reading!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you start by trimming whitespace from the String with this Swift code:

```
stringToTrim.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

Comment: This is the best solution - whitespace is trimmed only from beginning and end, not from the middle of a string. " Roger Rabbit " becomes "Roger Rabbit".

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3.0+**

Use `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` before comparison or `.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`

Answer (score -1):

**In Swift 4**
Use it on any *String* type variable.

```
extension String {
    func trimWhiteSpaces() -> String {
        let whiteSpaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: whiteSpaceSet)
    }
}
```

And Call it like this

```
yourString.trimWhiteSpaces()
```