# Swift version of Objective C rstrip: index problems

Tags: objective-c, string, swift, swift2

I am attempting to rewrite [this Objective C method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5691567/298607) that has similar functionality to Python's `lstrip` (which removes characters from the LH of a string) and `rstrip` (strips the RH of a string of characters).

The `lstrip` version works great:

```
// this works
func lstrip(st_in: String,
            trimSet: NSCharacterSet=NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())-> String {
    let wanted=trimSet.invertedSet
    if let r=st_in.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(wanted) {
        return st_in.substringFromIndex(r.startIndex)
    }
    return ""
}
```

I am having trouble with the `rstrip` version however.

This is what I have:

```
// does not compile
func rstrip(st_in: String,
    trimSet: NSCharacterSet=NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())-> String {
        let wanted=trimSet.invertedSet
        let tgt=String(st_in.characters.reverse())
        if let r=tgt.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(wanted) {
            // st_in.characters.count - r.startIndex
            return st_in.substringToIndex(st_in.startIndex.advancedBy((st_in.characters.count as Int) - (r.startIndex as Int)))
        }
        return ""
}
```

Issues:

1. The Swift version of `.rangeOfCharacterFromSet` does not seem to support `options:NSBackwardsSearch` -- I use forward search on `st_in.characters.reverse()` which *seems* to work;
2. The major issue (and my question is) `st_in.substringToIndex(st_in.startIndex.advancedBy((st_in.characters.count as Int) - (r.startIndex as Int)))` does not compile. I can *see* in the debugger that the values are correct, but `r.startIndex` is type `Index` and I cannot use that value directly for arithmetic nor can I coerce that to an Int value nor can I access the value I see in it.

So given this in the debugger:

```
56> st 
$R33: String = "  \t\n  I needz trimin'¡    \t\n\n\n\n"
 57> String(st.characters.reverse()) 
$R34: String = "\n\n\n\n\t    ¡'nimirt zdeen I  \n\t  "
 58> String(st.characters.reverse()).rangeOfCharacterFromSet(trimSet.invertedSet)!.startIndex 
$R35: Index = {
  _base = {
    _position = 9
    _core = {
      _baseAddress = 0x0000000101207ee0
      _countAndFlags = 9223372036854775839
      _owner = Some {
        instance_type = 0x0000000101207ec0
      }
    }
  }
  _lengthUTF16 = 1
}
```

You can see that `_position=9` in the Index structure -- just what I need in `st_in.substringToIndex(st_in.startIndex.advancedBy(st_in.characters.count - r.startIndex))` but I do not know how to access it in Swift.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rangeOfCharacterFromSet()` *does* support search from the end of the source string, but the Objective-C  `NSBackwardsSearch` is imported to
Swift as `.BackwardsSearch`:

```
func rstrip(st_in: String,
    trimSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())-> String {
        let wanted = trimSet.invertedSet
        if let r = st_in.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(wanted, options: .BackwardsSearch) {
            return st_in.substringToIndex(r.endIndex)
        }
        return ""
}
```

Example:

```
let s1 = " foo bar      "
let s2 = rstrip(s1)

print(">\(s1)<")
print(">\(s2)<")

// Output:
// > foo bar      <
// > foo bar<
```

So you don't need to operate on the reversed string.
But to answer your question anyway: This is how it would work:

```
func rstrip(st_in: String,
    trimSet: NSCharacterSet=NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())-> String {
        let wanted = trimSet.invertedSet
        let tgt = String(st_in.characters.reverse())
        if let r = tgt.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(wanted) {
            let length = tgt.startIndex.distanceTo(r.startIndex)
            return st_in.substringToIndex(st_in.endIndex.advancedBy(-length))
        }
        return ""
}
```

Instead of *casting* a string index to `Int` (which does not compile),
`distanceTo()` is used to compute the length as a `Distance`
(which happens to be `Int` for `String.CharacterView`),
and *that* can be used in arithmetic, e.g. `-length`.

Answer (score 1):

i use a little bit different approach. (i try to use 'pure Swift' and avoid to import Foundation as much, as possible. maybe i change my mind with Swift3.0 )

```
extension String {
    var rtrim: String {
        var s = self.characters
        while s.last == " " { s = s.dropLast() }
        return String(s)
    }
    var ltrim: String {
        var s = self.characters
        while s.first == " " { s = s.dropFirst() }
        return String(s)
    }
    var trim:String {
        return self.ltrim.rtrim
    }
}

let str = "\nalfa\nbeta\nga ma\n   delta   \n\na"
let c = str.characters
let trimmedLines = c.split("\n", allowEmptySlices: false).map{ String($0).trim }
print(str.debugDescription, trimmedLines)

// "\nalfa\nbeta\nga ma\n   delta   \n\na" ["alfa", "beta", "ga ma", "delta", "a"]
```