# How to iterate through the characters of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, string

```
NSString *myStrings = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

How could I iterate each of the letters (a, b, c, d, e, etc..) in an Objective-C `for` loop?

Comment: Keep in mind that your idea of a "letter" may not translate well to other locales.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way is to use a simple for-loop:

```
for (NSInteger charIdx=0; charIdx<myStrings.length; charIdx++)
    // Do something with character at index charIdx, for example:
    NSLog(@"%C", [myStrings characterAtIndex:charIdx]);
```

Comment: What does `%C` specify? I didn't know printf had a special format for unichars.

Comment: Please note that someone posting in <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158646/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-an-nsstring">this discussion</a> points out that Apple specifically discourages using characterAtIndex to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to use getCharacters:range: instead. You get the raw unicode array with one object call and can iterate over the result. The output is the same, but it's faster.

```
NSString *inputString = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
NSUInteger length = inputString.length;
unichar buffer[length+1];
// do not use @selector(getCharacters:) it's unsafe
[inputString getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%C", buffer[i]);
}
```

Comment: unichar is the type for utf-16: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unichar

Comment: If you are wondering what this is good for, it's a required in/out parameter for getCharacters:range: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408720-getcharacters?language=objc

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate substrings of NSString characters with a block

```
NSString *characters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
[characters enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, characters.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

     NSLog(@"substring: %@ substringRange: %@, enclosingRange %@", substring, NSStringFromRange(substringRange), NSStringFromRange(enclosingRange));

 }];
```