# iOS iterate through NSString

Tags: ios5, nsstring, loops

What's the best way to iterate NSString? Code like following:

```
int len = str.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
    // do something with c
}
```

looks ugly for me. I'd prefer something like

```
// does not compile, unfortunately
for (unichar c in str)
{
    // do something with c
}
```

Is there any way to write it more gracefully than my first code snippet?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the string? There are a lot of built in functions that let you skip simple string iterations.

Comment: In case anyone lands in this page as I did, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158646/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(NSString *subString in yourString){
    NSLog("The Substring is: %@", subString);
    // do anything you want with the substring in this loop
}
```

This must work(if not, you can define your string as `NSDictionary` and try again)

Comment: This does not work. NSString does not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'.