# Counting same letters in a word

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to count same letters in a word. For example: apple is my word and first I found whether 'a' exists in this letter or not. After that I want to count the number of 'a' in that word but I couldn't do that. This is my code which finds the specific letter;

```
if([originalString rangeOfString:compareString].location==NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Substring Not Found");
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Substring Found Successfully");


}
```

originalString is a word which I took from my database randomly. So, how to count?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: like when you found 'a' then you need to count a in you String ? please clear your Question

Comment: You could set an integer variable to keep track and increment it every time you get a match - e.g. something like: `int i = 0; if (![originalString rangeOfString:compareString].location==NSNotFound) i++;`

Comment: if you need the to know how many times the letter `a` is in the word apple you could use `regular expressions` try to match the letter a, and check the count of the matches.

Comment: Yes, I need to count a in my string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *strComplete = @"Appleeeeeeeeeeeeeee Appleeeeeeeee Aplleeeeeeeeee";
NSString *stringToFind = @"e";
NSArray *arySearch = [strComplete componentsSeparatedByString:stringToFind];
int countTheOccurrences = [arySearch count] - 1;
```

**Output :**

```
countTheOccurrences --- 34
```

Answer (score 3):

i have different idea let's try...

```
  NSString *string = @"appple";
    int times = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"p"] count]-1;

    NSLog(@"Counted times: %i", times);
```

Comment: Arrr, I also just wanted to write that ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could just [loop over the string once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158646/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-an-nsstring), adding each letter to an `NSMutableDictionary` (as the key) and keeping a tally of how many times the letter occurs (as the value).

The resulting `NSMutableDictionary` would hold the number of occurences for each unique letter, whereby you can extract what you like.