# How can i remove prefixed zeros from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string like  "00Welcome", "0000To", "0STACKOVERFLOW", "NOW".

Given a NSString, how can i remove zeros from prefix.

I thought initially to go with CharacterAIndex, but looks like not a good idea.

I have just gone through the below link:

[Most efficient way to iterate over all the chars in an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158646/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-an-nsstring)

Comment: Iteration ??.You can perform iteration. if you get some char != '0' you stop iterating else you rewriting this char to null

Answer (score 3):

If the zeroes are rare:

```
while ([myString hasPrefix:@"0"])
    myString = [myString subStringFromIndex:1];
```

Comment: This could potentially pollute the autorelease pool, depending on the amount of input and the amount of 0s.

Answer (score 3):

This will remove all 0s from both then beginning and the end using [`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBJFBGC):

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0"];

NSString *input = @"00Welcome";    
NSString *output = [input stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

---

Using regular expressions:

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^0+"];

NSString *input = @"00Welcome";    
NSString *output = [re stringByReplacingMatchesInString:input
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])
                                           withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will it remove only prefix, not suffix?

Comment: This will remove from the end too. If you want to remove only from the beginning I will post new code, but it won't be as simple.

Comment: @Whoami: Added a regular expression method which will remove 0s from just the beginning. gnasher729's is shorter and suitable for small input but may cause problems if you are parsing a lot of text. The regular expression method requires compiling only one regular expression object which you can reuse for all of your input.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for your valuable Input. You rock always!!. :)

Comment: May i ask can u give bit inside on why gnasher729's solution  leads to autorelease pool pollute, so that i can understand?

Comment: @Whoami: For gnasher729's solution, it creates new strings each iteration of the loop. If there are 5 zeroes at the beginning of the input, then gnasher729's solution creates 6 strings, that will all exist in memory at once. E.g., `00000Test`, `0000Test`, `000Test`, `00Test`, `0Test` and `Test`. This isn't a big problem if you are only processing a small number of strings, but if you are processing thousands of strings or the strings you are processing are very large, then it may be using memory very inefficiently.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str =@"000034234247236000049327428900000";
NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"^0*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
str= [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

Try this alternative use of regular expressions given by @dreamlax