# How do I loop through NSString N number of times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

how do I loop the string 9 times ?  (z x c v b n z x c)

```
NSString *fl = @"zxcvbn";
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you need to go through the characters and if there's less characters then the loop count start appending string to the end from the beginning?

Comment: no need for appending just stop tat that count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast and dirty snippet:

```
NSString *string = @"abcdef";
NSString *letter = nil;
int n = 9;
for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    // start over if it's more than the length
    int currentIndex = index % string.length;

    letter = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(currentIndex, 1)];

    NSLog(@"letter: %@", letter);
}
```

---

If you want a low-level example with detailed explanation [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397279/2177402).

Comment: Instead of the `while` loop, simply do `int currentIndex = index % string.length;`.

Comment: How can I get index path of letter ?

Comment: Isn't that `currentIndex`?

Comment: index 0  letter: a........ index 6 letter: g   again it repeats index 0 letter: a index 1 letter: b                                                                                                   how can I know repeated index ?

Comment: `index` always starts from 0 and `position = index + 1`

Comment: Can you explain briefly I am new to coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95827/discussion-between-islam-q-and-user5276912).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `substringWithRange` (which returns a `NSString`), you can also use `characterAtIndex` to get the character value:

```
NSInteger n = 9;

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    unichar character = [fl characterAtIndex:index % fl.length];

    // do something with `character`, e.g.
    //
    // if (character == 'z') { ... } 
}
```

Comment: what if i want loop again ? through the same string I mean second time

Comment: Use `index % fl.length` in that case, as rmaddy suggested.