# How to check each character in an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsstring

I have an `NSString` which contains a number, like 9823. Now I need to iterate though that string and print some statements based on the digit. For example, for digit 8 I should print ("A"), for digit nine: ("B") and so on. For checking I will use a `switch` statement, but I don't know how to iterate through each character in the number (again, it is an NSString). In `Swift` I can use `for in` loop, but because `NSString` isn't considered as an array in Objective-C, I can't use that here, so I wonder whether there  is any alternatives to `for in` in `Objective-C`, which can be used with `NSString`. I'm just learning `Objective-C`, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You could use `rangeOf:` that's simpler to find if there is a "8" or not, but  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158646/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-an-nsstring ?

Answer (score 0):

`NSRegularExpression` would be a very good fit here:

```
NSString *yourString = @"Greetings SEN 5241, LUH 3417 and THX 1138.";

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\d*?8\\d*)"
                                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                                         error:&error];
NSAssert(!error, @"%@", error);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString
                        options:kNilOptions
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, yourString.length)
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                         NSLog(@"%@", [yourString substringWithRange:result.range]);
                     }];
```

There are some very good online regular expression playgrounds (such as [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3ia76)) which can help. Additionally, regular expressions are a skill that's useful anywhere, in any language.