# In my macOS application, I am working with UserDefaults dictionaryRepresentation. Sometimes I get strings with unknown encoding. Any suggesition?

Tags: objective-c, nsstringencoding

I am working with a Objective-C Application, specifically I am gathering the dictionary representation of NSUserDefaults with this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDictionary *userDefaultsDict = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
```

While enumerating keys and objects of the resulting dict, sometimes I find a kind of opaque string that you can see in the following picture:

[image]

So it seems like an encoding problem.

If I try to print description of the string, the debugger correctly prints:

```
Printing description of obj:
tsuqsx
```

However, if I try to write obj to a file, or use it in any other way, I get an unreadable output like this:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is the following:

1. Detect in some way that the string has the encoding problem.
2. Convert the string to UTF8 encoding to use it in the rest of the program.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT: Very Hacky possible Solution that helps explaining what I am trying to do.**

After trying all possible solutions based on dataUsingEncoding and back, I ended up with the following solution, absolutely weird, but I post it here, in the hope that it can help somebody to guess the encoding and what to do with unprintable characters:

```
- (BOOL)isProblematicString:(NSString *)candidateString {

     BOOL returnValue = YES;

     if ([candidateString length] <= 2) {
         return NO;
     }

     const char *temp = [candidateString UTF8String];

     long length = temp[0];
   
        char *dest = malloc(length + 1);
   
        long ctr = 1;
   
        long usefulCounter = 0;
        for (ctr = 1;ctr <= length;ctr++) {
       
           if ((ctr - 1) % 3 == 0) {
              memcpy(&dest[ctr - usefulCounter - 1],&temp[ctr],1);
           } else {
               if (ctr != 1 && ctr < [candidateString length]) {
                   if (temp[ctr] < 0x10 || temp[ctr] > 0x1F) {
                       returnValue = NO;
                   }
           }
               usefulCounter += 1;
           }
       
       }
    memset(&dest[length],0,1);
    free(dest);

    return returnValue;
}

- (NSString *)utf8StringFromUnknownEncodedString:(NSString*)originalUnknownString {                       

    const char *temp = [originalUnknownString UTF8String];

    long length = temp[0];

    char *dest = malloc(length + 1);

    long ctr = 1;

    long usefulCounter = 0;
    for (ctr = 1;ctr <= length;ctr++) {
    
        if ((ctr - 1) % 3 == 0) {
            memcpy(&dest[ctr - usefulCounter - 1],&temp[ctr],1);
        } else {
            usefulCounter += 1;
        }
    
    }
    memset(&dest[length],0,1);

    NSString *returnValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dest];
    free(dest);


    return returnValue;
}
```

This returns me a string that I can use to build a full UTF8 string. I am looking for a clean solution. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's a perfectly valid string and has no encoding problems. `\x1a` is a non-printable character (substitute, ^Z). It includes other non-printable characters as well. This string is a valid `AppleMapID` and it comes from the `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`. The question here is - what are you trying to do? Is this some kind of accidental discovery and you're curious? Or are you going to work (modify, read) with this value?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest. I am trying to obtain a string representation of the dictionary entirely in UTF8. The last picture shows the result of my obtained string, saved to disk, and reopened in BBEdit. I need to get a string representation in entirely valid UTF8. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're talking about a string which comes from the `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`
(key `com.apple.preferences.timezone.new.selected_city`).

```c
NSString *city = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                  stringForKey:@"com.apple.preferences.timezone.new.selected_city"];
NSLog(@"%@", city); // \^Zt\^\\^]s\^]\^\u\^V\^_q\^]\^[s\^W\^Zx\^P
```

```
(lldb) p [city description]
(__NSCFString *) $1 = 0x0000600003f6c240 @"\x1at\x1c\x1ds\x1d\x1cu\x16\x1fq\x1d\x1bs\x17\x1ax\x10"
```

> What I would like to achieve is the following:
>
> 1. Detect in some way that the string has the encoding problem.
> 2. Convert the string to UTF8 encoding to use it in the rest of the program.
>
> &
>
> After trying all possible solutions based on dataUsingEncoding and back.

**This string has no encoding problem and characters like `\x1a`, `\x1c`, ... are valid characters.**
You can call `dataUsingEncoding:` with ASCII, UTF-8, ... but all these characters will still be
present. They're called [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (or non-printing characters). The linked Wikipedia page explains what these characters are and how they're defined in ASCII, extended ASCII and unicode.

What you're looking for is a way how to remove control characters from a string.

## Remove control characters

We can create a category for our new method:

```c
@interface NSString (ControlCharacters)

- (NSString *)stringByRemovingControlCharacters;

@end

@implementation NSString (ControlCharacters)

- (NSString *)stringByRemovingControlCharacters {
    // TODO Remove control characters
    return self;
}

@end
```

In all examples below, the `city` variable is created in this way ...

```c
NSString *city = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                  stringForKey:@"com.apple.preferences.timezone.new.selected_city"];
```

... and contains `@"\x1at\x1c\x1ds\x1d\x1cu\x16\x1fq\x1d\x1bs\x17\x1ax\x10"`. Also all
examples below were tested with the following code:

```c
NSString *cityWithoutCC = [city stringByRemovingControlCharacters];
// tsuqsx
NSLog(@"%@", cityWithoutCC);
// {length = 6, bytes = 0x747375717378}
NSLog(@"%@", [cityWithoutCC dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

### Split & join

One way is to utilize the [`NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1416371-controlcharacterset?language=objc).
There's a [`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415462-stringbytrimmingcharactersinset?language=objc)
method (`NSString`), but it removes these characters from the beginning/end only,
which is not what you're looking for. There's a trick you can use:

```c
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingControlCharacters {
    NSArray<NSString *> *components = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet];
    return [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

It splits the string by control characters and then joins these components back. Not a very efficient way, but it works.

### ICU transform

Another way is to use ICU transform (see [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general)).
There's a [`stringByApplyingTransform:reverse:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407787-stringbyapplyingtransform?language=objc)
method (`NSString`), but it only accepts predefined constants. Documentation says:

> The constants defined by the `NSStringTransform` type offer a subset of the functionality provided by the underlying ICU transform functionality. To apply an ICU transform defined in the ICU User Guide that doesn't have a corresponding `NSStringTransform` constant, create an instance of `NSMutableString` and call the `applyTransform:reverse:range:updatedRange:` method instead.

Let's update our implementation:

```c
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingControlCharacters {
    NSMutableString *result = [self mutableCopy];
    [result applyTransform:@"[[:Cc:] [:Cf:]] Remove"
                   reverse:NO
                     range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
              updatedRange:nil];
    return result;
}
```

`[:Cc:]` represents control characters, `[:Cf:]` represents format characters. Both represents the same character set as the already mentioned [`NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1416371-controlcharacterset?language=objc). Documentation:

> A character set containing the characters in Unicode General Category Cc and Cf.

### Iterate over characters

`NSCharacterSet` also offers the [`characterIsMember:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1407659-characterismember?language=objc) method. Here we need to iterate over characters (`unichar`) and check if it's a control character or not.

Let's update our implementation:

```c
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingControlCharacters {
    if (self.length == 0) {
        return self;
    }

    NSUInteger length = self.length;
    unichar characters[length];
    [self getCharacters:characters];
    
    NSUInteger resultLength = 0;
    unichar result[length];
    
    NSCharacterSet *controlCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet;
    
    for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        if ([controlCharacterSet characterIsMember:characters[i]] == NO) {
            result[resultLength++] = characters[i];
        }
    }
    
    return [NSString stringWithCharacters:result length:resultLength];
}
```

Here we filter out all characters (`unichar`) which belong to the `controlCharacterSet`.

### Other ways

There're other ways how to iterate over characters - for example - [Most efficient way to iterate over all the chars in an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158646/most-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-all-the-chars-in-an-nsstring).

## BBEdit & others

Let's write this string to a file:

```c
NSString *city = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                  stringForKey:@"com.apple.preferences.timezone.new.selected_city"];

[city writeToFile:@"/Users/zrzka/city.txt"
       atomically:YES
         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
            error:nil];
```

It's up to the editor how all these controls characters are handled/displayed. Here's en example - Visual Studio Code.

View - Render Control Characters off:

[image]

View - Render Control Characters on:

[image]

BBEdit displays question marks (upside down), but I'm sure there's a way how to
toggle control characters rendering. Don't have BBEdit installed to verify it.

Comment: Outstanding Answer zika ! all the methods work. The only left thing to do is to determine if a string needs such a conversion. Do you think I can call your code on all the strings and it will not change the strings that do not contain the control characters ? Thanks

Comment: You can call it on all strings. But be aware that the control character set contains characters like `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, ... Do you want to keep them? I don't know. If the answer is yes, create a [`NSMutableCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablecharacterset/1414334-controlcharacterset?language=objc) & remove them via the [`removeCharactersInString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablecharacterset/1414812-removecharactersinstring?language=objc) method. Like - `[controlCharacterSet removeCharactersInString:@"\n\r\t"]`.

Comment: Hello zrzka, I was thinking, is there a way to create a string literal from that problematic string ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's in the answer, your question, ... `@"\x1at\x1c\x1ds\x1d\x1cu\x16\x1fq\x1d\x1bs\x17\x1ax\x10"`.